# How do I spawn a secondary sword in the player hand when the player picks up a second sword from the floor?

Tags: godot

I'm having trouble implementing a dual wielding system. I want to spawn a secondary sword in the player hand when the player picks up a second sword from the floor.

As of now I'm using an item detector to check if I pass by items in certain groups if I do, and I press the pick up key, it will pick whatever item there. I managed to make it work with crossbow, spears, swords, shields and swords using main hand and offhand bone attachments.

But dual wielding swords is a problem.

```
elif body.is_in_group("Weapon3"):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("E"):
        var newWeapon3 = weapon3.instance() as Node
    
        if !attachment.has_node(newWeapon3.name):
            if attachment.get_child_count() > 0:
                droppedWeapon = attachment.get_child(0)
                droppedWeapon.queue_free()
                spawnDroppedWeapon(droppedWeapon.global_transform.origin)  # Spawn the dropped weapon on the floor
        
            attachment.add_child(newWeapon3) # Down till this point the previous code spawned the sword in the player's hand 
            player.has_Spear = false
            player.has_Rcrossbow = false
            player.has_Sword = true
            body.queue_free()
            if player.has_Sword:
                player.has_Sword_Off = true # This sets the Secondary sword as true, and a mirrored script for the offhand bone attachment instances another sword in the offhand. 
            print("Player has a sword")
```

So when I pick up a single sword, it instantly instances a sword both in the main hand and the offhand....which doubles the items, which isn't good.

For the shield it's not a problem

```
func _on_ItemDetector_body_entered(body):

    if body.is_in_group("Shield"):
        if Input.is_action_pressed("E"):
                var newWeapon1 = weapon1.instance() as Node
        
                if !attachment.has_node(newWeapon1.name):
                    if attachment.get_child_count() > 0:
                        droppedWeapon = attachment.get_child(0)
                        droppedWeapon.queue_free()
                        spawnDroppedWeapon(droppedWeapon.global_transform.origin)  # Spawn the dropped weapon on the floor
            
                    attachment.add_child(newWeapon1)
                    player.has_Sword_Off = false
                    player.has_Shield = true
                    body.queue_free()
                    print("player has shield")
```

Also using buttons or keybindings to instance one sword and then another works, it's just the item detector one that confuses me.

Comment: The more weapons you have, the more confusing it will be if your collector script is setting a bool for every weapon. Instead make a var that is an enum which you get from your weapon. Now if that is a sword and you get a second sword, place it to the offhand

Comment: @Zibelas but I have an animation system that requires bools to work anyways :/ like... if has_Sword : use the function dictacting sword animations.... if has other weapon, function that governs other animations and so on